# Select2 Dropdown for Jquery having open issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using select2 Dropdown for Jquery in my Asp.net application.

I am binding more than 1500+ records in the dropdown from the server side as we normally bind Asp.net application.

Using Select2 JS and css it will be worked as searchable.

Like I Specified

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dpId" CssClass="form-control select_project" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Javascript I used the below tag as I need to load all record in one time, which why I have not specified the Minimuminputlength.

```
$("select.select_project").select2({
    dropdownCssClass:"select_project"
});
```

Now the problem is when I click on dropdown to open it take around 10 second to open the dropdown.

Can you please help to resolved this issue?

Comment: since last 10 days i did not receive any answer , any one know that it is really urgent for me